# how to change string values in dictionary to int values

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

I have a dictionary such as:

```
{'Sun': {'Satellites': 'Mercury,Venus,Earth,Mars,Jupiter,Saturn,Uranus,Neptune,Ceres,Pluto,Haumea,Makemake,Eris', 'Orbital Radius': '0', 'Object': 'Sun', 'RootObject': 'Sun', 'Radius': '20890260'}, 'Earth': {'Period': '365.256363004', 'Satellites': 'Moon', 'Orbital Radius': '77098290', 'Radius': '63710.41000.0', 'Object': 'Earth'}, 'Moon': {'Period': '27.321582', 'Orbital Radius': '18128500', 'Radius': '1737000.10', 'Object': 'Moon'}}
```

I am wondering how to change just the number values to ints instead of strings.

```
def read_next_object(file):    
        obj = {}               
        for line in file:      
                if not line.strip(): continue
                line = line.strip()                        
                key, val = line.split(": ")                
                if key in obj and key == "Object": 
                        yield obj                       
                        obj = {}                              
                obj[key] = val

        yield obj              

planets = {}                   
with open( "smallsolar.txt", 'r') as f:
        for obj in read_next_object(f): 
                planets[obj["Object"]] = obj    

print(planets)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just adding the values into the dictionary `obj[key] = val` first check if the value should be stored as `float`. We can do this by using `regular expression` matching.

```
if re.match('^[0-9.]+$',val):  # If the value only contains digits or a . 
    obj[key] = float(val)      # Store it as a float not a string
else: 
    obj[key] = val             # Else store as string
```

Note: you will need to import the python regular expression module `re` by adding this line to the top of your script:  `import re`

Probably wasting some `0's` and `1's` here but **please** read these:

1. [The Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)
2. [Python data types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)
3. [Importing Python modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)
4. [Regular expression HOWTO with python](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

Stop trying to *'get teh codez'* and start trying develop your problem solving and programming ability otherwise you will only get so far..

Comment: is there a way to iterate over the whole dictionary and not to create a new list but instead just change the current dictionay??

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '12345'
num = int(s) //num is 12345
```

Comment: Handle it before you put it in the dictionary, trying to clean up after shoddy parsing is not the way to go.

Comment: but theres words and everthing in the text file>>

Comment: Yeah, that tends to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498484/convert-text-into-a-dictionary-with-certain-keys-and-values). If that is the case, you should consider intifying the value of "Orbital Radius" before you put it in your dictionary. My answer on that post actually does this for you:

```
elif line.startswith('Orbital Radius'):

    # get the thing after the ":". 
    # This is the orbital radius of the planetary body. 
    # We want to store that as an integer. So let's call int() on it
    rad = int(line.partition(":")[-1].strip())

    # now, add the orbital radius as the value of the planetary body in "answer"
    answer[obj] = rad
```

But if you really want to process the numbers in the dictionary after you've created it, here's how you can do it:

```
def intify(d):
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            intify(d[k])
        elif isinstance(d[k], str):
            if d[k].strip().isdigit():
                d[k] = int(d[k])
            elif all(c.isdigit() or c=='.' for c in d[k].strip()) and d[k].count('.')==1:
                d[k] = float(d[k])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i am using a different program then before so is there a way like a for loop of such then iterate over the dict?

Comment: @tomsmith: Note how the `intify()` function is using _recursion_.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget when i use the program above intify and print the dict it outputs "none"??????

Comment: @tomsmith: that's because it modifies the `dict` in-place. There's no return value

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-level recursive dict, as in your example, you can use:

```
for i in the_dict:
    for j in the_dict[i]:
        try:
            the_dict[i][j] = int (the_dict[i][j])
        except:
            pass
```

If it is arbitrarily recursive, you will need a more complex recursive function. Since your question doesn't seem to be about this, I will not provide an example for that.

Comment: Doesn't handle recursive dicts and thus would not work on the input provided in the question.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't see it was a recursive dict. Changed it now.